# Azure Worker Role not working properly

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

I have a Worker Role which isn´t working on Cloud environment.

When I run it locally, it runs perfectly, but, when I deploy it to Azure I´m having some troubles. The deploy, itself, occurs seamlessy, after the VM starts, my app doesn´t run. There is nothing on Event Log, and, even after I setted up the app to flush all Trace Messages to Azure Table, nothing is wrote there too.

How can I check if my app is really running on the VM? Why my app isn´t working there as it works locally?

Comment: Would u please define what do u mean by running? WaWorkerHost.exe is just the host process to load and run your worker role code and if it is running the Role DLL is loaded. Eventlog does not show anything because there may not be any specific activity or issue to log. If you explain how how your application runs in compute emulator and what you are expecting in Cloud, there may be some guidance u can get.

Comment: Do you have VS ultimate?  Sometimes enabling the intellitrace helps troubleshoot those situations.  I've had similiar issues and it turned out to be a dependency not being included in the dll.

Comment: If you don't have intellitrace, try opening the cspkg on your drive and finding the bin directory for your app to see if it has all the dlls in it you think it should.

Comment: Avkash: My first suspect was an exception in the code would get down the app, so I checked the event log, waiting for any kind of runtime error. The app is very simple. It has a set of Trace messages, after these messages it enter into a loop when it reads a azure queue, and for now, is only deleting the message. The DiagnosticMonitor is dumping the trace messages on Azure Tables. Locally.

Comment: So if you have a code which connects to outside endpoint, you can just install the Fiddler in your Azure VM to see if there is any network connection is established to your Azure queue. Because your role dll is loaded in host process and there is no exception, I dont see any specific reason why it is not running. Issue with trace message could be a separate issue which needs to resolved separately however in terms of your role it seems to act properly. IF you want to dig one more level up just installed the WinDBG in Azure VM to list all running thread and their call stack to verify your code.

Comment: @JasonHaley, if the DLL is missing form the project the worker role will generate an exception and host process could not run. In this situation the host process is running and portal status shows "Ready", missing DLL could not be problem at all.

Comment: I´ve added System.Data.Entity.dll and it finally worked. Anyway it´s so strange, it hadn´t logged any kind of exception, and the portal showed the "Ready" state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have tried to implement diagnostics on your webrole? This is the best way to find any errors in your code. An other solution is to install sysinternals during startup. Patriek van Dorp has made a nu get package thad adds the sysinternal suite as a plugin for your cloud project.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to enable RDP and remote into the machine.  Then you can look at the processes running and ensure that things are running as you expect.  It is odd that there is nothing in the event log if it is failing to run.  Does the portal show the deployment as Ready?

Comment: Yeah, the portal shows it as Ready. There is a process named "WaWorkerHost.exe", but the app is not running and nothing was logged in eventlog.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late, but i had similar issue.When i run it locally, it was running.After deploy did not run anything.Problem was that, i deploying into website,where worker not available.You should deploy into CloudService(there are available both roles) or make Sheduler, which will do request on your page, where process job you needed.In your custom intreval, ofcourse.

BTW sorry about my english ...

Regards